# I am so confused with associative arrays in php (two and 3 dimensional)

Tags: php, associative-array

I am learning php. In spite of so many examples on google, I am still confused about implementing arrays which are two dimensional and three dimensional. Can anyone explain, in simple terms, with an example please?

Comment: Try to avoid picking up random pieces of PHP from Google searches. You'll find your knowledge base a bit lacking. Instead, check out this PHP guide: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp. In particular, the section on arrays: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/0/0

Comment: @treeface: I agree. After floundering on Google, I finally found that book and started exploring, and I began to enjoy PHP. It's the best PHP book I've found, by far.

@user472625: Sitting down and going through a comprehensive book like that will give you a solid understanding of the basics and how to use them. And it's a lot more fun because you can track your own progress. Reading a bunch of random sites will leave you confused, but going through a progression of chapters all written by the same (experienced) teacher will mean you have a consistent understanding that you can build on later.

Comment: @Matt Ball: In PHP, all arrays are associative. Doing `array("foo", "bar", "baz")` is the same as `array(0 => "foo", 1 => "bar", 2 => "baz")`. In the first example, PHP just assigns the keys for you.

Comment: @willell: thanks, I was unaware - I'm not exactly a PHP guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There also is a very simple way to get started with multidimensional arrays.

Simply take a sheet and a pencil and start writing your multidimensional array down on paper first. It will help you a lot in the beginning.

It should look something like this.

```
ARRAY0 {
        key0.0 => "value0.0",
        key0.1 => "value0.1",
        key0.2 => ARRAY1 {
                          key1.0 => "value1.0",
                          key1.1 => ARRAY2 {
                                            key2.0 => "value2.0",
                                            key2.1 => "value2.1",
                                    },
                          key1.2 => "value1.2",
                  },
        key0.3 => "value0.3",
};
```

This is just my way of visualizing the arrays you can come up with your own syntax if you want.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest example for me was thinking of a SQL table as a multidimensional array.

The table might look like this:

```
ID | Name | Email
--------------------------
 1 | John | john@email.com
 2 | Jane | jane@email.com
```

And the array might look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => John
            [2] => john@email.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Jane
            [2] => jane@email.com
        )

)
```

The table is turned into an array of arrays. Where each row is accessed by the first index and each column by the second index.

So If I wanted to get "Jane" I would use $array[1][1]

An associative array of that same table might look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Name] => John
            [Email] => john@email.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Jane
            [Email] => jane@email.com
        )

)
```

You would access "Jane" like $array[1]["Name"]

Comment: You might want to add an example for associative arrays using the same "table example" to give more detail.

Answer (score 3):

These are arrays which are nested in other arrays. Depending on how deep they are nested determines what dimensional they are.

Here is an example of a 1D and 2D array, respectively.

```
$arr =
array(
   'item1' => 543,
   654 => true,
   'xas' => 0.54
);
// Accessing $arr[654] (returns true) 
$arr2 = array(
   array
   (
      'a' => 54,
      'b' => 'Hello'
   ),
   array
   (
       'itemx' => true,
       954 => 'hello'
   )
);
// Accessing $arr[0]['b'] (equal to 'Hello')
```

For a 3D array, you simply add another nested array into one of the 2nd level array items in the 2D array example.

Answer (score 1):

An array can have anything in it, from an integer to a string, to a full blown object, to another array.

Any array on its own is called a 1-dimensional array. If you think of it as a row of boxes, then it's a single row. If an array has another array in it then it's a 2-dimensional array: one of its boxes will be a column, adding another dimension.

```
$users = array() ;

$jim = array('Jim', 'Smith') ;

$users[] = $jim ;

//or in one step
$users = array(array('Jim', 'Smith')) ;

//then to access the first user:
$jim = $users[0]; 

//and his firstname:
$jimsname = $users[0][0] ;
//or
$jimsname = $jim[0] ;
```

You can access elements of the array and its nested arrays by indices, but you need to remember which numeric index corresponds to which piece of information. That's where you can use *associative* arrays, where the numeric indices are replaced by unique descriptive strings:

```
$users = array() ;

$jim = array(
    'firstname' => 'Jim', 
    'lastname' => 'Smith'
) ;

$users['jim'] = $jim ;

//then to access jim:
$jim = $users['jim']; 

//and his firstname:
$jimsname = $users['jim']['firstname'] ;
//or
$jimsname = $jim['firstname'] ;
```

That's pretty much it. You can see more [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php) and in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this simply.

```
$anArray['abc'][1]['qwe']='this is a value';
$anArray['abc']['avs']='another value';

echo $anArray['abc'][1]['qwe'];
echo $anArray['abc']['avs'];
```

/*

Array is a bit different in PHP. You can think of array elements as single variables ($anArray['abc'][1]['qwe'] or $anArray['abc']['avs']). And you can create them like single variables. This is an addition to conventional arrays. Conventional way is also supported.

But what happens if you write : `$anArray['abc']='something else';`

`$anArray['abc']` is just a string variable from that point. So you cannot (or may not as I didn't test it yet and practically everything is possible) access `$anArray['abc'][1]['qwe']` anymore.

So try to think the elements like variables, first ;)

*/